# O kivy usa recursos nativos?

Tags: python, kivy

Eu gostaria de saber se o *kivy* usa recursos nativos do sistema Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, usa, não sei se todos, mas ele acessa o que importa mais. Está escrito na [página principal do produto](http://kivy.org) (2o. parágrafo se considerar o de cima como título).